# Error updating all ArchLinux packages with -Syu

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, upgrade, pacman, yaourt

I am on Arch Linux with Kde.

I haven't updated the packages in a while and I'm having a problem while trying to do so:

The first thing I tried was: `sudo pacman -Syu` as the documentation says, and I get this error:

```
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 testing is up to date
 core is up to date
 extra is up to date
 community is up to date
:: The following packages should be upgraded first :
    pacman
:: Do you want to cancel the current operation
:: and upgrade these packages now? [Y/n] y

resolving dependencies...
looking for inter-conflicts...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: packagekit: requires pacman<3.6.0
:: package-query: requires pacman<3.6
```

I checked what version of pacman I had and I have v3.5.4:

```
 .--.                  Pacman v3.5.4 - libalpm v6.0.4
/ _.-' .-.  .-.  .-.   Copyright (C) 2006-2011 Pacman Development Team
\  '-. '-'  '-'  '-'   Copyright (C) 2002-2006 Judd Vinet
 '--'
                       This program may be freely redistributed under
                       the terms of the GNU General Public License.
```

Which seems to be ok I guess?

Just in case I tried to first update yaourt and I got the same message:

```
 testing is up to date
 core is up to date
 extra is up to date
 community is up to date
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: Starting full system upgrade...
:: packagekit: requires pacman<3.6.0
:: packagekit: requires pacman<3.6.0
```

I ran the following command to see if I could get the useful information and got [this](https://gist.github.com/1295503) from where I couldn't get any more useful information, but maybe you can.

Just in case I also tried it with KPackageKit and also got the same error:

```
:: packagekit: requires pacman<3.6.0
:: packagekit: requires pacman<3.6.0
```

I hope you have all the information you need, otherwise please ask. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two separate, but related, issues. First, `package-query` is an unsupported package (from the [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=35915)) and it is your responsibility to rebuild it whenever other dependencies—in this case `pacman`—are updated.

Uninstall it, update `pacman` and then rebuild `package-query` against the newer version.

Second, in addition to [Shawn's advice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22859/error-updating-all-archlinux-packages-with-syu/22871#22871) to force resynch your package list, you should ensure that you are synching to an up-to-date mirror.

Answer (score 2):

The first step would be to force a refresh of the master package list. This is done by `pacman -Syy`. Once that's done, try `pacman -Syu` again.

Comment: Nope, no luck! :(

Comment: If you do `pacman -Syy` there's no need to do `pacman -Syu` later. I mean, you can either run `pacman -Syy && pacman -Su` or `pacman -Syyu`.